# Transpose function for all data types

Tags: java, arrays

I have a function in java, which transposes a 2D array. But this function takes only double[][]. Is there a way to make it take all types of data type?(I mean like a global function that accepts any data type as input and returns result in that particular data type?) My code is as follows:

```
public static double[][] transpose(double[][] a)    
{
    double[][] trans = new double[a[0].length][a.length];
    if (a.length > 0)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < a[0].length; i++)
            {
            for(int j=0; j<a.length; j++)
                {
                    trans[i][j] = a[j][i];
                }
            }
    }return trans;  
}
```

Comment: A return method like this can only produce one type of data, so there is no good way for what you are describing to be done

Comment: ya.. so there is no  other alternative method i can try?

Comment: You can create a generic method that handles any non-primitive array, but any primitive array would require a separate method. See, for example, how Arrays.copyOf is implemented.

Comment: Matrix Transpose is something related to linear algebra, and because of this it's usually defined to take a double data type since it's the generic neumeric data type, if you want to get the transpose of a matrix of strings as an example, then it's better to define a generic method that deals with classes instead of primitive data types

Comment: @ManKeer This is interesting. Thank u.. will work on this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way but I think it isn't that good to go. You could make the return type of your function to `Object`:

```
public static Object[][] transpose(Object[][] a)    
{
    Object[][] trans = new Object[a[0].length][a.length];
    if (a.length > 0)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < a[0].length; i++)
            {
            for(int j=0; j<a.length; j++)
                {
                    trans[i][j] = a[j][i];
                }
            }
    }
    return trans;  
}
```

You could use this method by casting your array into an Object array and give it to the function:

```
    int[][] multi = new int[][] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 5 }, { 7, 6 }, { 9, 8 } };

    Object[][] o = new Object[multi[0].length][multi.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < multi[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < multi.length; j++) {
            o[i][j] = multi[j][i];
        }
    }

    transpose(o);
```

But note that you also have to cast the return value backwards:

```
    Object[][] returnValue = transpose(o);
    int[][] multiTransposed = new int[returnValue[0].length][returnValue.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < returnValue[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < returnValue.length; j++) {
            multiTransposed[i][j] = (int)returnValue[j][i];
        }
    }
```

This is a little tricky work around. You always have to know the data-type of your array before givving to the funtion. In my example it was `int`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This does help. This way I don't have to have separate functions for different types of data. Sure casting and recasting will take up a few lines of codes. But looks efficient in a bigger picture. Thank you

Comment: Mind that you are not just casting, you are allocating a third temporary array and use do a lot more allocations/moves than required. Probably, if you need efficiency, you'd better have a generic method and use reflection to direcly allocate a typed array.

Answer (score 1):

Using generics:

```
public static <T> T[][] transpose2DGeneric(T[][] a) {
    T[][] trans = a.clone();

    for (int i = 0; i < a[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            trans[i][j] = a[j][i];
        }
    }

    return trans;
}
```

If we use Lists instead of plain arrays we can get this:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> transpose2DList(List<List<T>> a) {
    List<List<T>> trans = new ArrayList<List<T>>(a);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.get(i).size(); j++) {
            trans.get(i).set(j, a.get(j).get(i));
        }
    }

    return trans;
}
```

So you can use `List<List<Integer>>, List<List<Double>>` ...